# Javascript regex matching too many characters

Tags: javascript, regex

My string is defined as;

```
var str = 'participant Tracking [[http://www.yahoo.com]] again [[more]]'
var res = str.match(/\[\[(.*[^\]])\]\]/g)
```

I would like to extract "http://www.yahoo.com" and "more" but I am getting

```
[ '[[http://www.yahoo.com]] again [[more]]' ]
```

What should the regex be?

Comment: Why oh why are you so greedy?

Comment: I can't help myself. I tried to with [^\]] but I was just too hungry

Comment: @PHemans What would be your output for this input `[[more[foo]bar]]`

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/yX0mN8/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`exec()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp) method in a loop, pushing the match result of the captured group to the results array. Also, remove the dot `.` greedy operator `*` from your capturing group because it is not necessary since you use negation.

```
var str = 'participant Tracking [[http://www.yahoo.com]] again [[more]]'
var re  = /\[\[([^\]]*)]]/g, 
matches = [];

while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  matches.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(matches) //=> [ 'http://www.yahoo.com', 'more' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting `]]` inside a negated character class won't give the result you want. Use inside a negative lookahead like below.

```
\[\[((?:(?!\]\]).)*)\]\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rA1lZ1/1)

```
> var str = 'participant Tracking [[http://www.yahoo.com]] again [[more]]'
undefined
> var re = /\[\[((?:(?!\]\]).)*)\]\]/g;
undefined
> var matches = [];
undefined
> while (m = re.exec(str)) {
..... matches.push(m[1]);
..... }
2
> console.log(matches)
[ 'http://www.yahoo.com', 'more' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'participant Tracking [[http://www.yahoo.com]] again [[more]]'
var res = str.match(/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/)
console.log(res[1]);
```

Comment: This satisfies the test case.  I'd be inclined to upvote if it was more than a "try this" answer.

Comment: You're right, I misread the question for some reason. I'll leave it as is, there are sufficient responses here.